# Facing issue while querying from two tables using 'with' in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

```
spark_df = spark.sql("""
with api_users as 
    (
        select 
            distinct(user_id)
        from 
            act_post
        where 
            dt = '2022-08-15'
            and upper(api_source) = 'API'
        limit 100 
    )
select 
    user_id
from 
    (
    unified_user_interest_profile
    )
where user_id in api_users.user_id
limit 100 
""")
```

ERROR

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 15, pos 0)

== SQL ==

with api_users as 
    (
        select 
            distinct(user_id)
        from 
            act_post
        where 
            dt = '2022-08-15'
            and upper(api_source) = 'API'
        limit 100 
    )
select 
    user_id
from 
^^^
    (
    unified_user_interest_profile
    )
where user_id in api_users.user_id
limit 100 
.
.
.
.
.

ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 15, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\n\nwith api_users as \n    (\n        select \n            distinct(user_id)\n        from \n            act_post\n        where \n            dt = '2022-08-15'\n            and upper(api_source) = 'API'\n        limit 100 \n    )\nselect \n    user_id\nfrom \n^^^\n    (\n    unified_user_interest_profile\n    )\nwhere user_id in api_users.user_id\nlimit 100 \n"
```

I am trying to create a temporary table as `api_users` and using the `user_id` column to query all the records from another table `unified_user_interest_profile` where `user_id` is present in  `api_users.user_id`

I am getting the above error and I couldn't understand what is the issue with it.

I am using this SQL command in pyspark to fetch the data.

Comment: Why don't you just do an inner join between 2 tables? the conditions looks straightforward to me

Comment: But I also need to filter the tables first. Not really sure how to do it @pltc

Answer (score 0):

The conditions looks pretty straightforward, so you can just do an inner join based on `user_id`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

api_users = (spark
    .table('act_post')
    .where((F.col('dt') == '2022-08-15') & (F.upper('api_source') == 'API'))
    .select('user_id')
    .distinct()
)

(spark
    .table('unified_user_interest_profile')
    .join(api_users, on=['user_id'], how='inner')
    .show()
)
```